# How to draw splines with muliple points in fabric.js using mouse

Tags: fabricjs

I am working on fabric.js and implemented all the elements like circle, rectangle etc.. using mouse we can draw all the elements. But currently I am working on splines (A line path with multiple points and vertexes). But not succeed.

I think fabric.Path is useful for it but I don't know how to implement.